# Mesure weight using force

Tags: raspbian, sensor, measuring

Is it possible to use [this](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1075) force-sensitive resistor to measure weight between 10g-5kg(0,4oz-176oz)?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to add an ADC as the Pi doesn't have analog inputs. There are probably more suitable modules which may cost less in the long run.

Comment: Can you please give me an example module that would be more suitable?